# Get the Record where only Two Records exists in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to get the parentID where **user1** and **user2** are using and only the two of them are using.

for example,

```
ParentTbl
| ID   |           Remarks              |
|------|--------------------------------|
| 1    | only one use this              |
| 2    | two user, _this is the ouput_  |
| 3    | three users use this           |

UserTbl
| ID | UserID | ParentID   |
|----|--------|------------|
| 1  |    1   |      1     |
|_2_ | ___1___|   ___2___  |
|_3_ | ___2___|   ___2___  |
| 4  |    1   |      3     |
| 5  |    2   |      3     |
| 6  |    3   |      3     |
```

It should be Parent 2

I already have :

```
select ParentID from UserTbl 
where UserID IN (1,2)
group by ParentID
having COUNT(*) = 2
```

But the output is wrong.

Comment: Do you want in the results the User data (the two users) or the Parent data (the parents with exactly 2 users)

Comment: Or just the ParentIDs: `SELECT ParentID FROM UserTbl GROUP BY ParentID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) = 2 ;`

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: Im sorry i must have mistyped my selected query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is

```
SELECT ParentID
FROM   UserTbl 
GROUP BY ParentID 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN userID IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
AND    COUNT(*) = 2
```

The first condition `SUM(CASE WHEN userID IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2` is to check User `1` and `2` are in

The second condition `COUNT(*) = 2` users count = `2` (only user 1 and 2)

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful

Answer (score -1):

I arrived to this answer, but I am not sure if it will give me the best performance.

I added a condition that excludes the invalid IDs where it is not equal to the specified users.

```
select parentid from UserTbl 
    WHERE parentID NOT IN (
                          SELECT parentID 
                          FROM UserTbl
                          WHERE userid NOT IN (1,2))
    AND userid IN (3,2)
    GROUP BY parentID 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) = 2
```

Comment: There are syntax error in this query

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, and does not require brackets